# How to get user meeting calendar event response message using Microsoft ews 2.0

Tags: java, calendar, exchangewebservices, appointment

I am having problem with getting the calendar event meeting response message that user send when accepting/denying the meeting in his mailbox. In general I send calendar notification (create new Appointment objects) for given users in my application. In java code I am able to get Appointment object, also AttendeeCollection, also I am able to get the response type with `attendee.getResponseType()`. But this is all.

I would like to show in my application the response that user gave while accepting/denying the invitation - the additional text that he gave. In fact this is an email that is sent with type MeetingResponse. It is not a EmailMesage type. I can get all emails from int inbox folder using this code:

```
Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox).findItems(new ItemView(100))
```

This gives me list of 100 emails, I can see theirs type, but how can I filter those meila, before performing the request, for the one meeting response that I am looking for. Is Attendee or Appointment somehow connected tho this email, it must I think, right? but how, what ID to use for the query, or maybe is there another way to get meeting response body ?

I am kind of stuck on this problem. The ultimate goal is to provide the message that user gave in my application.

I would appreciate any help, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe someone in the future will need it as well:

```
final Appointment appointment = Appointment.bind(service, new ItemId(appointmentId));
final SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ConversationId, appointment.getConversationId().toString());
final ItemView view = new ItemView(1);
view.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.ConversationId));
final FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, view); 
if (findResults.getTotalCount() == 1) {
      final Item item = findResults.getItems().get(0);
      item.load();
      return item.getBody();
}
```